# How to send a html email in AWS Lambda node js returning a well formed response for AWS api gateway

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, html-email, amazon-ses

I need to create an api that sends html emails through amazon SES.  I created properly my ses credentials and I want to create an AWS lambda in javascript (nodejs). Due the lack of good AWS documentation for sending an email using javascript, I need to know how to create a lambda that sends an email and responds with a proper message to AWS api gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The following was code written in javascript. Works perfect in AWS lambda and works great when is invoked from AWS Api gateway (no malformed message errors):

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var ses = new aws.SES({
accessKeyId: "Your SES Access Key",
secretAccesskey: "Your Secret key",
region: "us-east-1" // CHANGE with the region where you configured SES
});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
var requestPath = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.pathParameters));
var requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
var responseBody = {};
var response = {};

if (
requestBody &&
requestBody.emailFrom &&
requestBody.subject &&
requestBody.htmlBody
) {
var emailTo = requestPath.emailto;
var emailFrom = requestBody.emailFrom;
var subject = requestBody.subject;
var htmlBody = requestBody.htmlBody;
} else {
responseBody = {
    result: "fail",
    resultCode: 400,
    description:
    "Incorrect Parameters. Mandatory: emailFrom, subject and bodyHTML"
};

response = {
    statusCode: 400,
    headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(responseBody),
    isBase64Encoded: false
};

callback(null, response);
}

var emailParams = {
Destination: {
    ToAddresses: [emailTo]
},
Message: {
    Body: {
    Html: {
        Data: htmlBody
    }
    },
    Subject: {
    Data: subject
    }
},
Source: emailFrom
};


var email = ses.sendEmail(emailParams, function(err, data) {
var resultCode = 200;
if (err) {
    var responseBody = {
    result: "FAIL",
    resultCode: 500,
    description: "Error sending email: " + err
    };
    resultCode = 500;
} else {
    var responseBody = {
    result: "OK",
    resultCode: 200,
    description: "Email sent successfully"
    };
}



response = {
    statusCode: resultCode,
    headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(responseBody),
    isBase64Encoded: false
};
callback(null, response);
});
};
```